# "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, electron

```
const electron = require('electron');
var mysql = require("mysql");
const app = electron.app;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow;
app.on('ready', function(){
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:1024, height:768, backgroundcolor:'#2e2c29'});
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '1.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));

});
```

Comment: Do you have electron installed yet ?

Comment: yes I have installed electron....

Comment: But it is undefined so it has problems with app. Check that you installed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Quick Start](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/) of Electron. When you have installed everything correctly like you said it should get you working.